# SQL Condition in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT posts.id, username, cover, audio, title, postDate, commentsDisabled,
       MAX(postClicks.clickDate) as clickDate,
       COUNT(*) as ClickCount
FROM postClicks INNER JOIN
     posts
     ON posts.id = postClicks.postid INNER JOIN
     users
     ON users.id = posts.user
WHERE posts.private = 0
GROUP BY postClicks.postid
ORDER BY ClickCount
LIMIT 5
```

This query gets me the top 5 results ORDER BY Count which is ClickCount. Each postClicks in my database has a clickDate what I am trying to do now is with the 5 results I get back, put them in order by ClickCount within the past 24 hours, I still need 5 results, but they need to be in order of ClickCount with 24 hour period.

I use to have this in the where clause:

```
postClicks.clickDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

But after the 24 hour period I would not get 5 results, I need to get 5 results.

My question is, can I put a condition or case in my order by clause?

Comment: `but they need to be in order of ClickCount with 24 hour period` ... can you show us what this actually means to do, by way of example output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a condition in the `ORDER BY` in this query, because that would affect the `LIMIT`.  Instead, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT pc5.*
FROM (SELECT posts.id, username, cover, audio, title, postDate, commentsDisabled,
             MAX(postClicks.clickDate) as clickDate,
             COUNT(*) as ClickCount,
             SUM(postClicks.clickDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as clicks24hours
      FROM postClicks INNER JOIN
           posts
           ON posts.id = postClicks.postid INNER JOIN
           users
           ON users.id = posts.user
      WHERE posts.private = 0
      GROUP BY postClicks.postid
      ORDER BY ClickCount
      LIMIT 5
     ) pc5
ORDER BY clicks24hours DESC;
```

Comment: @user979331: if this is the answer you're accepting, please click on the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It will turn green, and other users will know this is the answer that worked for you.